# Как поставить image-объекты в canvas - Screen Space - Overlay

Tags: unity3d

Немного сложно описать что я хочу сделать.

Есть Canvas - Screen Space - Overlay и объекты с компонентом image(Canvas - родитель , image-объект - дети)

Нужно не просто перенести объекты на сцену в "зоне камеры" , а расположить их на площади canvas , что бы потом игрок смог их видеть

Не так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Canvas:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Знаю , немного глупый вопрос

Покажу на примере текста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я разместил сам на текст на полотне canvas и как видно оно у меня корректно 
отображается игроку при этом я его не размещал на области видности камеры.

Как видим текст не расположен на области видности для камеры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделайте еще хотя бы скрины компонентов Canvas и камеры, пока не понятно нечего

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы поместили под "не так" и "вот так". Нужно более внятное описание. Overlay вообще подразумевает "натягивание" Canvas поверх окна вашей камеры. И первый вариант - как раз то, поведение, которое он выдаёт. Что находится на втором варианте я не понимаю)

Comment: Вы явно что-то делаете не так. Границы Канвы в режиме "Оверлей" и есть предел видимости камеры для всех объектов на этой Канве. ЗАЧЕМ Вам размещать дочерние объекты Канвы за ее пределами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:
Если я добавляю объект , и добавляю компонент image,то разместить объект на поле canvas'а я не могу. Если же я добавлю ui элемент image , то все работает как нужно.

- Image вручную (лучше так не делать) :

Перетаскиваем sprite на сцену:

Сам спрайт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спрайт на сцене:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляем к спрайту компонент image:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у нас таким образом не получается сделать "адекватный" image-объект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Через Ui-элемент:

Добавляем объект таким образом(правый клик на пустом месте окна иерархии):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вашего ui-элемента должен быть родитель canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему не можете разместить? Может у вас неправильно стоят координаты или привязки?

Comment: Все-таки решил проголосовать против, так как ответ ничего не объясняет, а только запутывает. Нет объяснения не только *почему* нужно сделать вот так, а даже что конкретно нужно сделать. Добавьте объяснение и я уберу минус.

Comment: Теперь вижу. Да, SpriteRenderer отвечает за отрисовку объекта в мире, а Image - в канвасе. И координаты они по-разному считают. Поэтому совмещать их в одном объекте было неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

На объекте background3 у компонента Image в полое Color - альфа канал на нуле

Comment: Дело не в этом.